# Efficient algorithm to compute the Heesch number of a shape

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, tiling

The [Heesch number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heesch%27s_problem) of a shape is the maximum number of layers of copies of the same shape that can surround it. For example the following shape (in the center) has a Heesch number of 4, because we can get at most 4 layers to surround it:

[image]

Given a shape, is there an efficient algorithm to compute its Heesch number? The only thing I can think of is to do a brute-force BFS search, surrounding it layer by layer. But this seems awfully inefficient.

Comment: The outer layer on the picture contains four gaps between slots, so it's not enough spikes. Is it on purpose?

Comment: @HEKTO It just means that another layer cannot be made.